# Select Query in Data Driven Web Application

Tags: html, sql, database, visual-studio, ms-access

So what i'm trying to do here is run a small data driven website in Visual Web Developer 2008. I have created a database using Microsoft Access and connected it to my web application. My database has 2 tables in it, The Person table and the Item table. Here's a list of what it would look like:

**Person Table**

```
PersonID(PK),
Name,
Birthdate,
Age
```

**Item Table**

```
ItemID(PK),
PersonID(FK to Person.PersonID),
Item Name,
Item Size,
Item Weight
```

I created a drop down list that displays they Name field of the Person table. What i want to make happen is for the Label i have set at the bottom to display two fields from the Item table that are connected to the person selected from the drop down list. I've been trying to structure that query in code but i'm having a pretty hard time with this one. Anyone have any idea's how this could work or even just tips on how to handle this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this for homework?

Comment: not specifically, I just finished a class on SQL and am trying to teach myself web developer for my next course so it won't be as difficult as this SQL course was.